# Solving Square matrix equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

A is a Square matrix, and we have the following function `t(A)=Σ(i=1 to n)a(ii)` it equals to the sum of the diagonal elements of the matrix.

1. Prove that for every matrix A,B from the same order, `t(AB)=t(BA)`
2. Prove that there isn't any matrix A,B from order NxN so that `AB-BA = In`

I was trying to prove the first and got stuck in the beginning.
that was my attemp:

`t(AB) = Σ(i=1 to n) Σ(j=1 to n) aij * bji`

and I didn't know how to continue from here, or even if that was the right starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start.  Do the same for $t(BA)$, and then interchange the names $i$ and $j$.

Comment: what do you mean by `interchange` the names of i and j.
i did the same for t(BA) and got t(BA)= Σ(i=1 to n) Σ(j=1 to n) bij * aji.
still not sure how to continue from here. I'd try to say t(AB)=t(BA).
but I'm not sure how I could solve this equation. since it has a sigma (Σ).

Comment: Replace every $i$ by $j$ and every $j$ by $i$.  You can interchange the order of summation.

Comment: First thanks for your response. If I will change every i and j. I will get the following: `(BA)= Σ(j=1 to n) Σ(i=1 to n) bji * aij` , and `t(AB) = Σ(j=1 to n) Σ(i=1 to n) aji * bij`. and I'm not sure I understand what you actually mean since I don't see how I can continue from here.

Comment: $t(BA ) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} a_{ji}$.   Interchange $i$ and $j$ and it's $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ji} a_{ij}$.  Now change the order of summation: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n$ becomes $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n$.  Finally, use the commutative property of multiplication: $b_{ji} a_{ij} = a_{ij} b_{ji}$.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert!